# NoClassDefFoundError on getting methods from dependency classes via reflections

Tags: java, reflection

I have been using the [Reflections](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections/) lib to find all methods annotated with a specific annotation on some classes inside a dependency I have. The methods these dependencies provide are not being used, I just want to scan them for usage of an annotation.

Sample of my code:

```
public List<Method> searchClassesForMethodsAnnotatedWith(List<Class<?>> targetClasses, Class<? extends Annotation> annotation){
        List<Method> filteredMethods = new ArrayList<>();
        targetClasses.forEach((targetClass) -> {
            Reflections temporaryReflections = new Reflections(targetClass.getName(), new MethodAnnotationsScanner());
            Set<Method> foundMethods = temporaryReflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith(annotation);
            foundMethods.forEach((method) -> {
                filteredMethods.add(method);
            });
        });
        return filteredMethods;
    }
```

The list of classes passed as an argument to the method was populated on another method, that looked inside the dependency for classes that had a specific extension.

Although, I am getting an exception back:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/star/uno/RuntimeException

    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at com.Statistics.Maestro_Running.MaestroParser.lambda$searchClassesForMethodsAnnotatedWith$1(MaestroParser.java:57)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at com.Statistics.Maestro_Running.MaestroParser.searchClassesForMethodsAnnotatedWith(MaestroParser.java:56)
    at com.Statistics.Programs.compileDataFromMaestro(Programs.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.star.uno.RuntimeException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 29 more
```

I don't understand how I was abled to look for extensions inside the classes, and I am receiving an error on checking for methods. What should I do?

Comment: How did you get that `List<Class>`?

Comment: The one passed as argument to my example method? Like I explained there, it was populated on another method that looked inside the dependency for classes that had a specific extension. I can post its code if it helps...

Comment: then you are using Reflections library incorrectly, you should not load any Class instances yourself

Comment: But I am not, I guess... I am just looking for the classes that have a specific extension. Then, for each class, I am getting its path and using reflections to retrieve their methods... Isnt it the right way to go?

Comment: can you explain `specific extension` part?

Comment: On my dependency, I have some classes that extend `ComponentBase.class`. That `List<Class>` you mentioned is a list of class objects using that extension. I retrieved that with reflection's `getSubTypesOf`

Comment: Are you willing to use different library? As this one sadly is a bit limited for more advanced lookups - you would need to do most of the work alone.

Comment: Sure, have any suggestions?

Comment: Posted an answer that uses ClassGraph instead, as with Reflections you would need to manually iterate over raw data (just multi map of strings with method signatures etc, pain to deal with, but possible if you will really need it)

Comment: Thank you kind sir, will take a look in a minute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using Reflections library incorrectly and because of that you are loading some classes that normally would not load - and that classes might have dependencies on some non existing classes. (in your class path)

Sadly Reflections library have a pretty poor API for more advanced queries, you can try use something different like ClassGraph (io.github.classgraph) or use Reflections store manually to find only the exact values you need.

In ClassGraph you can do it like that:

```
// based on example from github page
try (ScanResult scanResult = new ClassGraph().enableAllInfo().whitelistPackages("pkg").scan()) {    
    // probably could be changed to some other code that would return methods directly from class graph, but it does the same job.
    List<Class<?>> classes = scanResult
        .getClassesWithMethodAnnotation("pkg.MyAnnotation")
        .filter(clazz -> clazz.extendsSuperclass("pkg.BaseComponent"))
        .loadClasses();
    List<Method> methods = classes.stream()
        .flatMap(c -> Stream.of(c.getMethods()))
        .filter(m -> m.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Alternative way:

```
List<Method> methods1 = scanResult
    .getSubclasses("pkg.BaseComponent").stream()
    .flatMap(c -> c.getMethodInfo().stream())
    .filter(m -> m.hasAnnotation("pkg.MyAnnotation"))
    .map(MethodInfo::loadClassAndGetMethod)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note that you only need to load classes that actually contain that method AND are extending that class, and nothing more.

If you will still get errors like that, then it means that one of that classes contains dependencies on something that you don't have on class path, you can either try to add this dependence so it will work just fine, or skip these classes from loading: by using `.loadClasses(true)` instead. (true == ignore exceptions) In alternative way you would need to catch this error yourself while calling to `loadClassAndGetMethod`.

Comment: It did not work... The classes get scanned and added to `classes` list just fine, but I get the same error I reported whenever I use `getMethods` on them. Actually, it is behaving the same way as it did with Reflections. If I am missing a dependency, how are the classes being loaded correctly, and I get an error on method retrieving?

Comment: Can you maybe check all that annotated methods? And see if any of them use `com/sun/star/uno/RuntimeException` and if you have this class on classpath? as this is the class you seems to be missing. But this might be also caused by using different class loader... Hard to say without seeing the code. but like I said in the answer, you can try to use `.loadClasses(true)` to ignore errors and check if this will be enough for you.

Comment: I have found the reason... The depdendency I was scanning had some dependency that (for some reason) was not added to the jar I was referencing on build. So I had to go look for it and add the dependency manually. Thanks for your help. BTW, Reflections lib was not the issue.

Comment: but for advanced queries it is still better to use something like that - as otherwise you might end up loading a lot of classes, but good that issue was solved.